# How to properly use the Child of constraint with bones

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints

I am trying to get 2 bones to follow each other using the constraint system. 
[image]

Trying to get the hand to follow the pump here. Both bones are individually configured correctly...
[image]

This is what happens when I add the constraint. Anybody understand the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the Set inverse button in the constraint settings

**Set Inverse**
By default, when you parent your owner to your target, the target becomes the origin of the owner’s space. **This means that the location, rotation and scale of the owner are offset by the same properties of the target.** In other words, the owner is transformed when you parent it to your target. This might not be desired! So, if you want to restore your owner to its before-parenting state, click on the Set Inverse button.

https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html

Comment: Looks like that did it. Thanks for the help! Gotta wait 6 minutes to be able to accept your answer...

Comment: Thanks for this adegner! Still works in Blender 2.9. I found that after setting the initial Target armature, I had to press Set Inverse and once more after selecting the specific bone. Works great for animation